# Is it redundant to use "troubleshooting" and "problem" in the same sentence?

Tags: redundancy

Is it ok to say something like *"Troubleshooting hardware and software issues"*, or as troubleshoot already implies there is a problem, the sentence is somewhat redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's perfectly OK. We use phrases like "identify and troubleshoot an issue" all the time in the tech word.

> Mac OS X: How to **troubleshoot a software issue**
>   Learn ways to identify and troubleshoot software issues.

(https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201516)

The word "troubleshoot" no doubt implies there's something wrong, but it is not ungrammatical to say "troubleshoot an issue" or "troubleshoot a problem":

> "cited the service it performed in **trouble-shooting an employee problem**"

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=troubleshoot))

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot does imply the existence of a problem. Troubleshoot does not specify this to be hardware or software problem in particular. Hence it is not *tautological* to use troubleshooting and problem in the same sentence.

Answer (score -2):

I think you mean *redundant*.

But, no, it's not uncommon to state that, but some people may think it's redundant.

Comment: Troubleshooting refers to the process of identifying why there is problem and what needs to be done to fix it.